# Range A4:A100 not working with .getRange in Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

It has been working with `value = thisSheet.getRange("A4").getValue();` but not when I change it to the range `"A4:A100"`

This is my code:

```
function EqualValue() {
  var allSheetTabs,i,L,thisSheet,thisSheetName,sheetsToExclude,value;

  sheetsToExclude = ['Template','Summary','Count'];

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  allSheetTabs = ss.getSheets();

  L = allSheetTabs.length;

  for (i=0;i<L;i++) {
    thisSheet = allSheetTabs[i];
    thisSheetName = thisSheet.getName();

    //continue to loop if this sheet is one to exclude
    if (sheetsToExclude.indexOf(thisSheetName) !== -1) {continue;}

    value = thisSheet.getRange("A4:A100").getValue();
    if(value >= "15") sendEmail(value)
  }
```

Any suggestions are more than welcome

Comment: Not sure what your are trying to do.  You are request a range but only getValue() did you mean getValues()?  And if so it will return a 2D array so not sure what you want to check against "15".  And do you really mean 15?  If you want to check the value"s" in A4:A100 you would need to loop through the array  and test each value[i][0] where i is 0 to number of rows -1?

Comment: Effectively each day is a new row I want to check that the number in row a (Stock) is greater than 15 .

@TheWizEd What do you mean about loopin through?

Comment: Do you want to check only the latest day > 15?  Send only 1 email?

Comment: Yes. I wouldn't want it sending email from previous days @TheWizEd if an email had already been sent

Comment: Maybe explain why A4:A100.  Maybe I can figure out what your want.

Comment: Colmun A It will display the stock number that is input via google form day by day. A4:A100 is just a estimate has all our stock tends to have a 50-70 day turnover. a Day = a row.

Comment: Sorry its still not clear what you want.

Comment: Ok Sorry:

Column A is the row with all the number of stock. It is updated daily with a number. If the number is greater than or equal to 15 then I want and email to be sent to stock management that says the stock of Item A is currently #.

I don't want an email sent on the 21st December that is referring to the stock on December 5th or December 20th. 

In short: I want an email sent that tells me the stock of the item if it is greater than or equal to 15 on a daily basis @TheWizEd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the exact same function like this:

```
function EqualValue() {
  var allSheetTabs,i,L,thisSheet,thisSheetName,sheetsToExclude,value;

  sheetsToExclude = ['CheckBoxes','Globals'];

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  allSheetTabs = ss.getSheets();

  L = allSheetTabs.length;

  for (i=0;i<L;i++) {
    thisSheet = allSheetTabs[i];
    thisSheetName = thisSheet.getName();

    //continue to loop if this sheet is one to exclude
    if (sheetsToExclude.indexOf(thisSheetName) !== -1) {continue;}

    value = thisSheet.getRange("A4:A100").getValue();
    Logger.log('%s-The value in %s is %s',i+1,thisSheet.getRange('A4:A100').getA1Notation(),value)
    if(value >= "4") Logger.log('%s-The value in %s is %s and it is greater than or equal to 4',i+1,thisSheet.getRange('A4:A100').getA1Notation(),value);
  }
}
```

It works and here's my Logger.log results:

```
[18-12-17 11:59:24:195 MST] 3.0-The value in A4:A100 is 
[18-12-17 11:59:24:305 MST] 4.0-The value in A4:A100 is 
[18-12-17 11:59:24:380 MST] 5.0-The value in A4:A100 is 3.0
[18-12-17 11:59:24:459 MST] 6.0-The value in A4:A100 is 
[18-12-17 11:59:24:541 MST] 7.0-The value in A4:A100 is 4.0
[18-12-17 11:59:24:543 MST] 7.0-The value in A4:A100 is 4.0 and it is greater than or equal to 4
[18-12-17 11:59:24:616 MST] 8.0-The value in A4:A100 is 4.0
[18-12-17 11:59:24:618 MST] 8.0-The value in A4:A100 is 4.0 and it is greater than or equal to 4
[18-12-17 11:59:24:690 MST] 9.0-The value in A4:A100 is
```

I used "4" instead of "15".  I thought it would just return the upper left cell and it does.  So maybe it's your `sendEmail(value)` function.

Comment: Then what do you need A4:A100 for it will always be A4?

Comment: I'm not suggesting that it's a sensible thing to do.  I've just noticed that it will return the upper left cell value.  I've even seen people do `sh.getRange("A4").getValues()` and that also will return the value in value[0][0]. I was just running the code to verify the stated problem.  That's the whole point of [mcve] I think.

Comment: I see. That makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You say "Column A is the row" but A is a column.  I'm assuming what you mean is column A of each tab has a list of values.  Also assuming daily a new value is added to the list at the bottom(?).  When you compare the value with 15 you sendEmail, but how do you know which tab?

I've added tab name to the sendEmail function, you should be able to figure that out.

```
function EqualValue() {
  try {
    var sheetsToExclude = ['Template','Summary','Count'];
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var allSheetTabs = ss.getSheets();
    for( var i=0; i<allSheetTabs.length; i++ ) {
      var sheet = allSheetTabs[i];
      if( sheetsToExclude.indexOf(sheet.getName()) >= 0 ) continue;
      // I'm assuming you keep adding to A column and only want the last one?
      var values = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),1,1,1).getValue();
      if( value >= 15 ) {
        sendEmail(sheet.getName(),value);  // You will get an email for every tab that passes test
      }
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean how do you know what tab passes the test? Thats my next step. Get the name of the tab and add it into the subject and body of the email